# Working on a Dropbox Application. Not able to link the application activity to the Dropbox login page

Tags: android, dropbox

I am using this code. Manifest.xml permission are done.

```
private static String app_key = "88888888888";

private static String app_secret = "*******************";

private static final int REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX = 0;

private TextView mTestOutput;

private Button mLinkButton;

private DbxAccountManager mDbxAcctMgr;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mLinkButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mDbxAcctMgr = DbxAccountManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext(), app_key, app_secret);

    mLinkButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            callmethod();
        }
    });
}

private void callmethod() {
    mDbxAcctMgr.startLink(MainActivity.this,REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX );
}
```

Comment: It might help if you told us what the problem is. Are you getting an error? If so, what?

Comment: Thanks smarx!! . when i am running this app on my phone it runs perfectly . but when i run this on emulator this shows Application is doing too much work .  i would like to ask you one more question that.. I don't want user to fill their login details on browser , i want them to fill the details on Activity is it possible. because when i am running this app it jumps to the browser which shows the login page of the dropbox.

Comment: Nothing in the code you shared should block the UI thread. When are you seeing the "Application is doing too much work" message? (Is it when you launch your app? When you click the link to log in with Dropbox? Before or after the web browser comes up?)